# How to add a new constraint using ConstraintList() and "rule" in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am working in a optimization problem that has many iterations, and for each iteration the size of problem increases.

I am trying to use **model.c = ConstraintList()** to create my set of constraints.
And later I have to add new constraints.

Today I am using **model.c.add(expr)**. However, I would like to use **model.c.add(rule=my_rule)**

But this provide the error **add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rule'**

Using **.add(expr)** works fine, but using **rule** would improve the performance of the algorithm.

I can't use **model.c = Constraint(rule=my_rule)** because I don't have the exactly size of the problem in the first iteration.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: I don't understand why you could not use `model.c = Constraint(rule=my_rule)` inside of a  while loop or such and use that to add a constraint on each iteration?

Comment: That wouldn't work, because I would replace model.c on each iteration. I should use model.c.add(expr) in this case.